# How to put together two string arrays in C Programming

Tags: c, arrays, string, 2d

I have this Project. I have arrays with scores, match1, match2 and i have names of the players and their countries abbreviations. then i have those abbreviations and the long names of the country.

I can put together the players name and the country abbreviations, also i can put toggether the country abbreviations and the country long names.

But I don't know how to put together in one array the country long names and the players names.

So, I created the array (char name_and_country[PLAYERS][LENGTH_NAME]) and I want in this array to be names and countries ; so if i printed to say:

char name_and_country[PLAYERS][LENGTH_NAME]={ "David Beckham England", "Wayne Rooney England "....etc.

Can anyone help me with that?
Thank you in advance!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#define PLAYERS 5
#define NUM_COUNTRIES 3
#define LENGTH_NAME 40
#define LENGTH_CODE 4
#define LENGTH_COUNTRY 20


int main (void)

{   int match1[PLAYERS] = { 0,1,3,2,4};
    int match2[PLAYERS] = { 0,4,0,0,1};
    int goals[PLAYERS] ;

    char name[PLAYERS][LENGTH_NAME] ={"David Beckham","Wayne Rooney","Pirlo", "Del Piero","Lionel Messi"};
    char country_abbreviations[PLAYERS][LENGTH_CODE] = {"ENG","ENG","ITA","ITA","ARG"};
    char country_code[NUM_COUNTRIES][LENGTH_CODE] = {"ARG","ENG","ITA"};
    char country_name[NUM_COUNTRIES][LENGTH_COUNTRY] = {"Argentina", "England","Italy"};
    char name_and_country_code[PLAYERS][LENGTH_NAME];
    char country_code_and_country_name[NUM_COUNTRIES][LENGTH_COUNTRY];
    char name_and_country[PLAYERS][LENGTH_NAME];
    int i, first =1, second= 2;

 for(i=0; i < PLAYERS; i++)
    {
        strcpy (name_and_country_code[i], name[i]);
        strcat (name_and_country_code[i], "  " );
        strcat (name_and_country_code[i], country_abbreviations[i]);
        goals[i]= match1[i] + match2[i];
        printf("Player %s----- score %d:\n", name_and_country_code[i], goals[i]);
    }
```

Comment: So, what did you expect and what actual output did you get?

Comment: I expect something to look like this :
`char name_and_country[PLAYERS][LENGTH_NAME]={ "David Beckham England", "Wayne Rooney England "....etc.`

I dont know how to do it . I think it needs to us a functions strcnpy and stchr

Comment: @userXXX Well, what you already have with `strcat()` should do the job. Do you get any errors?

Comment: @H2CO3 , No I dont get any errors because on those statement I am putting together the country abbreviations and the players name .

i want to put together the country full name and the players name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Code. I have added my code into your code and here is the result. I ran it , it works fine..

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include<string.h>
#define PLAYERS 5

#define NUM_COUNTRIES 3
#define LENGTH_NAME 40
#define LENGTH_CODE 4
#define LENGTH_COUNTRY 20


int main (void)

{   int match1[PLAYERS] = { 0,1,3,2,4};
        int match2[PLAYERS] = { 0,4,0,0,1};
        int goals[PLAYERS] ;

        char name[PLAYERS][LENGTH_NAME] ={"David Beckham","Wayne Rooney","Pirlo", "Del Piero","Lionel Messi"};
        char country_abbreviations[PLAYERS][LENGTH_CODE] = {"ENG","ENG","ITA","ITA","ARG"};
        char country_code[NUM_COUNTRIES][LENGTH_CODE] = {"ARG","ENG","ITA"};
        char country_name[NUM_COUNTRIES][LENGTH_COUNTRY] = {"Argentina", "England","Italy"};
        char name_and_country_code[PLAYERS][LENGTH_NAME];
        char country_code_and_country_name[NUM_COUNTRIES][LENGTH_COUNTRY];
        char name_and_country[PLAYERS][LENGTH_NAME];
        int i, first =1, second= 2;

        for(i=0; i < PLAYERS; i++)
        {
                strcpy (name_and_country_code[i], name[i]);
                strcat (name_and_country_code[i], "  " );
                strcat (name_and_country_code[i], country_abbreviations[i]);
                goals[i]= match1[i] + match2[i];
                printf("Player %s----- score %d:\n", name_and_country_code[i], goals[i]);
        }
        for(i=0; i < PLAYERS; i++)
        {
                strcpy (name_and_country[i], name[i]);
                strcat (name_and_country[i], "  " );
                char country[LENGTH_COUNTRY];
                strcpy(country,"DEFAULT COUNTRY"); // Used when player has a invalid country code
                int j;
                for(j=0;j<NUM_COUNTRIES;j++)
                {
                        if(strcmp(country_abbreviations[i],country_code[j])==0)
                                strcpy(country,country_name[j]);
                }
                strcat(name_and_country[i],country);
                printf("%s\n",name_and_country[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: what does this "DEFAULT COUNTRY " do , should it be initialiazed or something,

i put this one my program but i still dotn getm them right .

Comment: What was the ouput you got? post it here
I mean contents of the array name_and_country

Also post contents of the array name_and_country_code (which you made)

Comment: `for(i=0; i < PLAYERS; i++)
    {
        strcpy(name_and_country[i], name[i]);
        strcat(name_and_country[i], "  ");
        char country[LENGTH_NAME];
        strcpy(country,"DEFAULT COUNTRY ");
        for (j=0 ; j < NUM_COUNTRIES; j++);

        {
            if( strcmp(country_abbreviations[i], country_code[j]))
                strcat (name_and_country[j], country);

        }
        strcpy(country,country_name[i]);`

Comment: `---------------Players are David Beckham  .
---------------Players are Wayne Rooney  .
---------------Players are Pirlo  .
---------------Players are Del Piero  DEFAULT COUNTRY .
---------------Players are Lionel Messi  .
`

Comment: There was a small mistake in using strcmp. Now i have corrected it and added the complete code above. Use it , it is working fine on my system.
Hope it helps!